# Cancel the Runnable in the .runOnFirstFix() method of LocationOverlay Object

Tags: java, android, multithreading, interrupt, runnable

I have an application the leans heavily on map functionality. From the first Activity I call the `runOnFirstFix()` method to load a lot of data from a database once the location of the user has been found, but I also want to be able to interrupt this runnable and stop it mid execution for when I switch activity or the user presses the button to stop it running.

```
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mc.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
                mc.setZoom(15);
                userLatitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
                userLongitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();
                userLocationAcquired = true;
                loadMapData();  //Here the method is called for heavy data retrieval    
            }
        });
```

How can I stop this Runnable mid execution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the handler object to handle this runnable.

define this runnable with the runnable object.

after that in handler you can start the cancel this runnable service

for e.g.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

on startCommand()

```
handler.postDelayed(myRunnable,5000);
```

this will execute the run method of runnable after 5 sec

for cancel

```
handler.removeCallbacks(myRunnable);
```

and your runnable define like this way

```
private Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){
      public void run(){
          // do something here
      }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/Handler.html

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: How will this make you able to stop the execution of `myRunnable` once it has started?

Answer (score 2):

You could (and probably should) use an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

```
private class MapLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Data> {
    @Override
    protected Data doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return loadMapData();  //Here the method is called for heavy data retrieval, make it return that Data  
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Data result) {
    //do things with your mapview using the loaded Data (this is executed by the uithread)
    }
}
```

and then in replace your other code with

```
final MapLoader mapLoader = new MapLoader();
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        mc.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        mc.setZoom(15);
        userLatitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLatitudeE6();
        userLongitude = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation().getLongitudeE6();
        userLocationAcquired = true;
        mapLoader.execute();
    }
});
```

then you should be able to cancel the running task when you no longer want it to complete using

```
mapLoader.cancel(true);
```

I hope the code compiles, I  haven't tested it, but it *should* work :)

Just make sure that it is the ui thread that creates the MapLoader

edit: I think you need to wrap the `mapLoader.execute();` call in a `runOnUiThread()` call in order for it to work correctly since `runOnFirstFix()` might spawn a new thread

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can call `interrupt()` on a running thread which should stop the execution of given thread. But if any kind of blocking operation like `wait()` or `join()` is being performed, `InterruptedException` will be thrown. Even some kinds of socket-related blocking operations can lead to `InterruptedIOException` under Linux, or under Windows the operation still remains blocked (since Windows does not support interruptible I/O). I think you still could interrupt your runnable, just be aware that some I/O may not be interrupted until finished and if blocking, it might throw those kind of exceptions I mentioned.

Comment: In my example though, how can I get reference to the Thread that calls my Runnable which comes from the method runOnFirstFix()?

Comment: I'm no Android guru, but after I've checked the sources of `MyLocationOverlay`, I can see that the runnable passed in is actually not even executed in separate thread. So you can either call `runOnFirstFix(null)` before the execution itself starts, or to stop it during execution, you'll have to create a `Thread` (which implements `Runnable`).

Comment: A `Thread` won't work since the underlaying code will use it as a simple `Runnable` object and only use the `run()` method and ignore the fact that your supplying a `Thread`

Comment: @getekha: You are completely right, I was probably very tired yesterday :( Another way would be to fire your own thread from the `Runnable` that's passed in.