# getting exception in runOnFirstFix

Tags: android, multithreading, toast, runnable

I am getting the following exception

```
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2852
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at android.widget.Toast$TN.<init>(Toast.java:317)
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:91)
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:233)
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at com.mid.nash.activity.MapPageFragment$3$1.run(MapPageFragment.java:156)
09-19 18:09:36.551: E/AndroidRuntime(20608):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Following is my code

```
myLocationOverlay.runOnFirstFix(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        //check if the location is within boundaries. 
        GeoPoint currentlocation = myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation();
        double latitude = (currentlocation.getLatitudeE6() / 1E6);
        double longitude = (currentlocation.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6);
        //check if user is witin boundry of Kew
        if (latitude <= RESTRICTED_UPPERLEFT_LAT && 
                latitude >= RESTRICTED_BOTTOMRIGHT_LAT && 
                longitude >= RESTRICTED_UPPERLEFT_LNG && 
                longitude <= RESTRICTED_BOTTOMRIGHT_LNG){
            mapController.animateTo(myLocationOverlay.getMyLocation());
        } else {
            myLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "You are out of scope.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        }
    }
});
```

I have referred to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6665798/cancel-the-runnable-in-the-runonfirstfix-method-of-locationoverlay-object) thinking this might help me. But I was not able to implement the method mentioned.

How to get rid of this exception?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `Runnable` is executing on a thread that doesn't have a `Looper` which is required to post a `Toast`.  What you would need to do is create a `Handler` in your `MapPageFragment` that you can send a message to for it to show the `Toast`. Or don't use a `Toast` at all, you can implement a much nicer notification UI.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest moving the Toast out of your Runnable.

A Toast should be called in the main thread with other UI elements. I had a problem yesterday where a background thread was destroyed and the Toast never closed. It was present on the Home Screen and everywhere else until I forcibly removed the app the cached memory... Toasts are nice but keep them on the main thread.

As a note, you don't call `show()` so the Toast won't do anything at the moment anyway...